# Smoothly transition tab activation in Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4, css-transitions, bootstrap-tabs

I have created a page with bootstrap tabs at the bottom of the page.

The tabs themselves are of varying heights and I found it jarring how the browser just snaps to a lesser page height as I activate a tab with smaller overall height (and the page was scrolled to far down).

After trying half a dozen suggestions I ultimately arrived at a solution where I make all tabs same height, but I still wanted at least some transition between them and opted for opacity.

See my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b2gwr6mf/).

HTML

```
<div class="consistent-height">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">tab 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <img class="logo" alt="logo" src="/static/images/logo_icon.svg">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane active">
      tra la la
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade">
      juhuhu
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.logo {
  float:  right;
  height: 20em;
}

.tab-content {
  padding-top: 2em;
}

.consistent-height .tab-content {
  position: relative;
  transition: opacity .5s ease 0s;
}

.consistent-height .tab-content > .tab-pane {
  display:    block; /* undo "display: none;" */
  opacity:    0;
  position:   absolute;
  width:      calc(100% - 15em);
}

.consistent-height .tab-content > .active {
  opacity: 100%;
}
```

This works almost good, but there's an additional delay when I move from "tab 2" to "tab 1" (vs immediate transition when activating "tab 2").
I suspect that the delay is caused by overlapping transitions, but I don't understand them well enough to understand what it is that's bothering the browser here.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.fade` class is applying additional css styling related to the opacity.
only the second tab has the `.fade` class, hence why it feels inconsistent.

If you add `.fade` to both, you will notice the delay on both transitions.

*not sure why you added `.fade`, it seems to be meant to be used with Modals. you might have defined it yourself and where unaware that bootstrap also has a fade class*

```css
.tab-content {
  padding-top: 2em;
}

.consistent-height .tab-content {
  position: relative;
}

.consistent-height .tab-content>.tab-pane {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 15em);
  transition: opacity .5s ease 0s;
}

.consistent-height .tab-content>.active {
  opacity: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1> no fade </h1>
<div class="consistent-height">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">tab 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane active">
      tab 1 content
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane">
      tab 2 content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h1><br> with fade </h1>
<div class="consistent-height">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">tab 3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab4">tab 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane fade active">
      tab 3 content
    </div>
    <div id="tab4" class="tab-pane fade">
      tab 4 content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Thank you. Just removing the fade class immediately fixed the issue. It must have been a remainder of my many attempts to get some sort of smooth transition working.